# How to add a SSD disk to a google compute engine instance with Ansible?

Tags: google-compute-engine, ansible, solid-state-drive, google-cloud-platform

Ansible has the gce_pd module: http://docs.ansible.com/gce_pd_module.html. According to the documentation you can specify the size and mode (READ, READ-WRITE) but not the type (SSD vs. Standard). Is it possible to use the gce_pd module to create a SSD disk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of right now, https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/blob/devel/cloud/google/gce_pd.py has no mention of `SSD` at all, so it seems like it's not supported. If this is something that you really need, consider submitting a feature request.

Answer (score 1):

This is now available in Ansible.

According to the [updated official docs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/gce_pd_module.html), `disk_type` was added in Ansible 1.9

`disk_type` can have these possible values:

- `pd-standard`
- `pd-ssd`

Here's an example:

```
# Simple attachment action to an existing instance
- local_action:
    module: gce_pd
    name: mongodata
    instance_name: www1
    size_gb: 30
    disk_type: pd-ssd
```